# How to move div to the right from current position using transition?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to make a div move from it's current position to the right(`left: 1000px`) using transitions? How can I do that and trigger it using Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Check the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwvxg8v7/)

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>

<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

Here's a simple example using vanilla js:

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");

box.addEventListener("click", moveBox);

function moveBox() {
    box.classList.add("move");
}
```

```css
#box {
  background-color:blue;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  left:0;
  transition:left .33s ease;
  position:relative;

}

#box.move {
  left:500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">

</div>
```

and here is is on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cx7n88s0/

To use `left`, you need to set a position of relative or absolute.

Use `transition` on the main id or class